# batch replace spaces on filenames in html

Tags: html, regex, wordpress

I have a lot of old html pages that I've imported to wordpress and it's all good except for the images. There's thousands of images with spaces in the filenames and wordpress doesn't seem to allow them to be uploaded without editing the spaces out.

Anyone know how I could mass edit html like below to replace the spaces in just the filenames with "_".

```
<img src="product 1_logo.jpeg" />
<img src="company 2_logo.jpeg" width="400"/>
<img src="product 3_logo.jpeg" title="something" />
<img src="product 4_poster.jpeg" />
<img src="product 5 - something_logo.jpeg" />
```

Lines like those to make look like:

```
<img src="product_1_logo.jpeg"/>
<img src="company_2_logo.jpeg" width="400"/>
<img src="product_3_logo.jpeg" title="
<img src="product_4_poster.jpeg"/>
<img src="product_5_-_something_logo.jpeg"/>
```

So if possible something like a regular expression to replace empty spaces between `<img src="` and then the next `"` with a `_` would work.

Any help would be massively appreciated. I'm over my head here :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace to replace blank space with "_"

```
$image = "product 1_logo.jpeg";
$imgname = str_replace(' ', '_', $image);
<!-- Or--> 
$imgname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $image);
```

Check if it will help..!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python solution using `lxml`,
(WARNING: it will overwrite the original file)

```
from lxml.html import parse
from sys import argv
with open(argv[1]) as f:
   page=parse(f)
   for img in page.xpath("//img"):
     src=img.get("src")
     src=src.replace(" ","_")
     img.set("src",src)

page.write(argv[1])
```

Call it like this

```
python script.py filename
```

Or use `find` to apply it to all your tree

```
find -iname '*.html' -exec python script.py {} +
```

Comment: Cool. I will definitely try that later when I have time.

Comment: I'm not much for python or php or anything but I'll give it a go! I also figured a workaround for anyone maybe bumping into this via google in the future. I can just copypaste the files as is to "\wp-content\uploads" and then just use find and replace in libreoffice or whatever to replace "<img src="" with "<img src=\wp-content\uploads\". That works, just isn't a pretty or the right way to accomplish this really.

Comment: Your regexp fails on the first tag with any attribute before the src